# Javascript: window.onload problem

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window, onload

This isn't working in IE (although it does work in FFX). Why?

Using HTML in the header:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

    // And finally, let's call the code ourselves.
    window.onload = lbp.init;

</script>
```

And then the script:

```
// lbp is the script's universal variable, which retains everything
var lbp = {};

// The sequence of functions to trigger
lbp.init = function() {
    alert('hi');
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if IE supports `application/javascript`. Did you try `text/javascript`?

Also: is `lbp` initialized before setting `window.onload`?

Comment: This is the correct answer! I will make it so as soon as my waiting period is up. It was application/javascript, just like you guessed. Thanks, I completely overlooked it =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have declared `lbp` after `window.onload = lbp.init;` code. Your code is not working because of the sequence issue.

Try the code in the following sequence.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var lbp = {};
        // The sequence of functions to trigger
        lbp.init = function() {
        alert('hi');
    }
        
    // And finally, let's call the code ourselves.
    window.onload = lbp.init;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

IE does not support application mime types except for with PDFs.  This means IE will completely ignore your JavaScript.  Change it to mime type `text/javascript`.